# Calculating timing offsets in a text file

Tags: sed, peoplesoft

I'm using **sed** to process a very long PeopleSoft trace file. The trace file is full of information, but I am interested in how long each step took to process, and the number of rows affected in the database by the step.

I have a *fairly ugly* bash script which is basically a one-line series of sed pipes. It works pretty quickly, so it is OK. Of course I would welcome any suggestions to clarify the code.

I must say that while it is ugly, it is clear (to me) what sequential steps it is going through. Often sed/awk one liners are completely unintelligible to a non-expert.

```
#!/bin/bash

sed '/./=' "$1" | sed '/./N; s/\n/ /' | sed '/--/!d' | sed '/-- B/d' | sed '/--  /d' | sed '/Instance/d' | sed '1,/Application Engine ended normally/!d' | awk '/Row/ {n = $0; getline; print $0 n; next } 1' > "$1".txt
```

**Timings**

Most lines contain timing information, in the format for HH:MM:SS. Many statements are running subsecond so the timing field often doesn't change. I'd like to produce a new field which is the offset of the previous line. Only the seconds need to be considered as most operations are subsecond anyway.

```
246 -- 14.54.43 .(TL_TIMEADMIN.MAIN.Step040) (PeopleCode)238 -- Row(s) affected: 1
247 -- 14.54.43 Program Skipping Step due to non-zero return code from PeopleCode at TL_TIMEADMIN.MAIN.Step040
249 -- 14.54.43 .(TL_TIMEADMIN.MAIN.Step050) (Call Section TL_TIMEADMIN.DISPATCH)
251 -- 14.54.45 ..(TL_TIMEADMIN.DISPATCH.Step02a) (PeopleCode)
253 -- 14.54.45 ..(TL_TIMEADMIN.DISPATCH.Step02a) (SQL)
266 -- 14.54.45 ..(TL_TIMEADMIN.DISPATCH.Step02b) (Call Section TL_TA000200.TA000200)258 -- Row(s) affected: 1
268 -- 14.54.46 ...(TL_TA000200.TA000200.Step001) (PeopleCode)
270 -- 14.54.46 ...(TL_TA000200.TA000200.Step001) (Call Section FUNCLIB_TLTA.STEPMSG)
```

I would like to see something like this:

```
246 -- 14.54.43 0 .(TL_TIMEADMIN.MAIN.Step040) (PeopleCode)238 -- Row(s) affected: 1
247 -- 14.54.43 0 Program Skipping Step due to non-zero return code from PeopleCode at TL_TIMEADMIN.MAIN.Step040
249 -- 14.54.43 0 .(TL_TIMEADMIN.MAIN.Step050) (Call Section TL_TIMEADMIN.DISPATCH)
251 -- 14.54.45 2 ..(TL_TIMEADMIN.DISPATCH.Step02a) (PeopleCode)
253 -- 14.54.45 0 ..(TL_TIMEADMIN.DISPATCH.Step02a) (SQL)
266 -- 14.54.45 0 ..(TL_TIMEADMIN.DISPATCH.Step02b) (Call Section TL_TA000200.TA000200)258 -- Row(s) affected: 1
268 -- 14.54.46 1 ...(TL_TA000200.TA000200.Step001) (PeopleCode)
270 -- 14.54.46 0 ...(TL_TA000200.TA000200.Step001) (Call Section FUNCLIB_TLTA.STEPMSG)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK with an awk solution?

```
{
  split($3, time, ".")
  if (NR == 1) prev = time[3]
  $3 = $3 " " time[3] - prev
  prev = time[3]
  print
}
```

output:

```
$ awk -f time.awk input
246 -- 14.54.43 0 .(TL_TIMEADMIN.MAIN.Step040) (PeopleCode)238 -- Row(s) affected: 1
247 -- 14.54.43 0 Program Skipping Step due to non-zero return code from PeopleCode at TL_TIMEADMIN.MAIN.Step040
249 -- 14.54.43 0 .(TL_TIMEADMIN.MAIN.Step050) (Call Section TL_TIMEADMIN.DISPATCH)
251 -- 14.54.45 2 ..(TL_TIMEADMIN.DISPATCH.Step02a) (PeopleCode)
253 -- 14.54.45 0 ..(TL_TIMEADMIN.DISPATCH.Step02a) (SQL)
266 -- 14.54.45 0 ..(TL_TIMEADMIN.DISPATCH.Step02b) (Call Section TL_TA000200.TA000200)258 -- Row(s) affected: 1
268 -- 14.54.46 1 ...(TL_TA000200.TA000200.Step001) (PeopleCode)
270 -- 14.54.46 0 ...(TL_TA000200.TA000200.Step001) (Call Section FUNCLIB_TLTA.STEPMSG)
```

Comment: An awk solution is just fine... and very clear code also. Thank you very much.

Comment: In the past I've stayed away from sed/awk/grep for complex problems as I found most materials either too simple or else keyboard diarrhoea. Your code is very clear & helpful - thank you.